# How to make Ant aware of package location?

Tags: java, ant

I have Ant project and I just run ant in the directory where build.xml is located:

```
$ant
```

That gives me the following error (I suppose this a compilation error):

```
package <package> doesn't exist
```

I've downloaded the missing package. What should be done in order to make ant aware of the package location?

I've tried to set environment variable CLASSPATH but with no luck.

Comment: OK, I've found the command line option -lib <path>. So now I build the project like this:

    $ant -lib <path_to_downloaded_package>

Nevertheless, the error doesn't go away

Comment: We can't tell why an unknow error is thrown by unknown code, sorry.